# Difference between Ethernet and Ethernet cables?

Tags: ethernet

Though I have read definitions of Ethernet on many websites and everywhere, what I read is that it is a technology. I do not get what do they exactly mean by technology. Is Ethernet the same as an Ethernet cable or are they different?

Comment: It can mean the same thing and it can not mean the same thing, It all depends on context. Can you provide the context you are wondering about?

Comment: It's like the difference between "video" and "video cables".

Comment: How is this not a duplicate 5 years after Super User was launched?

Comment: It's like the difference between _electricity_ and _power cords_.

Comment: I was going to answer - "It's like the difference between water and the different means of transporting it, pipes, jugs, etc." Ethernet is a set of rules of hot to transport those bits of data. The cable is one way of doing it, WiFi, another.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

An Ethernet cable is one that conforms to the standards stipulated for Ethernet networking.

Ethernet as a whole is a group of networking technologies that together make up the Ethernet standard.  It includes both wiring and signalling standards, speed standards, duplexing, addressing standards - MAC addresses for network devices.  It includes the structure of a datagram (a packet), and how they should be switched and bridged.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet

Comment: Although perhaps it's painfully obvious, the clear distinction may be in that Ethernet functions quite well without any cables at all (i.e. 803.11 Ethernet a.k.a. "WiFi") …

Answer (score 0):

Different by nature: Ethernet has the category of technology while (an) Ethernet cable has the category of physical assembly.

Answer (score -1):

Ethernet is a common LAN standard with a transmission rate of 10Mbps. In Ethernet, all computers are connected to a coaxial cable, using a conflict-tested carrier sensing multiple access (CSMA/CD) method, using a competitive mechanism and bus topology. Basically, Ethernet is made up of Shared transmission media, such as twisted pair cable or coaxial cable and multi-port hub, bridge or switch. In a star or total line configuration, hubs/switches/Bridges connect computers, printers, and workstations to each other through cables.

An Ethernet cable is one of the most popular forms of network cable used on wired networks. Ethernet cables connect devices together within a local area network, like PCs, routers, and switches.

Comment: Your first and last paragraphs are completely unintelligible for someone asking questions this basic.